# In which case will this error occurs "Restricted dimension(s): ga:userAgeBracket, ga:userGender can only be queried under certain conditions"?

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I'm using Google Analytics Core Reporting API v4. When I query using the dimensions: ga:userAgeBracket & ga:userGender, I get the following error:

> Restricted dimension(s): ga:userAgeBracket, ga:userGender can only be queried under certain conditions

Can someone tell me why this error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all dimensions and metrics can be queried together.  This can be for several reasons it may not make sense to have them mixed.  It may also be that a relation between them does not exist.

My guess would be that there is no relation between  ga:userAgeBracket, ga:userGender.  Gender came from double click cookie.

Comment: This happens only for a specific Google Analytics Profile. The same query works fine in all the other profiles.

Comment: And demographic and interest reports are enabled for that view?

Comment: @dalmTo is correct, this has to do with a change that was announced in the [Google Analytics API Changelog](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/changelog) on Tuesday, Feb 14th, 2017. "Non-AdSense linked views will be restricted from querying for AdSense dimensions and metrics. Querying for these dimensions and metrics with a non-AdSense linked views will result in an error."  which should result in `Restricted metric(s): ... can only be queried under certain conditions.`

Comment: @KarthickShiva did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @NickRussler There is no change to this answer.  You can only use these dimensiosn when its allowed

Comment: But they are allowed according to the [referenced google resource](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) and also these exact queries worked for years with every other profile, which @KarthickShiva also mentioned above.

Comment: @NickRussler I think it occurs only to specific profiles, some of them disabled Demographics in their profiles and others had just enabled Demographics in their profile.